# writing media queries for almost every other pixel

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a page on my react project which contains the data of customers in card format and right now there are 3 card horizontally on my screen, now the problem is , i am trying to make it responsive and when i tried to do it whenever I slightly decrease the width of the screen the last card goes to next line and leaving a big chunk of space on the last line, for overcoming this problem i started to add media queries and decreasing my card width slighlty , but the problem arised that i have to do it after every 2 pixels, do i have to write the media query for every 2 pixels? Or is there any other way ? Here is the screenshot of the problem :-
[image]

```
Here is my JSX for this card only:-
<div className={`${customercss.parts} ${customercss.customer_card}`}>
                                <div className={customercss.card_wrap}>
                                <div className={customercss.customer_card_details} id={customercss.heading}>
                                    <div className={customercss.customer_name}>
                                        {elem.customer_name}
                                    </div>
                                    <label className={customercss.select_option}>
                                         <input type="checkbox" name="checks" value={elem._id} id="checkbox" onClick={(e)=>selected_items(e,elem)} />
                                         <span class={customercss.checkmark_span} ></span>
                                    </label>  
                                </div>
                                <div className={customercss.customer_card_details} id={customercss.customer_address}> <LocationOnOutlined htmlColor='#f7c6c6'/> {elem.customer_address}</div>
                                <div className={customercss.customer_card_details} id={customercss.date}> <CalendarToday htmlColor='#f7c6c6'/> {elem.date}</div>
                                <div className={customercss.customer_card_details} id={customercss.customer_other_options}>
                                    <div className={customercss.customer_other_options_parts} id={customercss.option1}>
                                        <div id={customercss.option1_1}>Subscriptions</div>
                                        <div id={customercss.option1_2}>{elem.customer_items.length}</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className={customercss.customer_other_options_parts} id={customercss.option2}>
                                        <MoreHoriz id={customercss.threedots} onClick={()=>{editcustomer(elem); show_edit_customer_details(elem)}} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
```

Here is the CSS(I have just added the css of the main box not the inside css) :-

```
.customer_card_box{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.customer_card{
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%), 0 8px 16px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
    background-color: white;
    width: 15rem;
    height: 13rem;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

@media (max-width:1034px){
    .customer_card{
        width: 14rem;
    }
}

@media (max-width:979px){
    .customer_card{
        width: 13.5rem;
    }
}

@media (max-width:949px){
    .customer_card{
        width: 13rem;
    }
}

@media (max-width:920px){
    .customer_card{
        width: 13rem;
    }
}

.card_wrap{
    margin: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: If you use fixed units like rem you will get this problem.How about setting width relative to viewport width and when you think that would make a card too small put in a media query to change the layout. Possibly grid would help you.

Comment: if i add media query i will get the same problem of making media queries for every other pixel wouldn't i? @AHaworth

Comment: The thing I was trying to suggest was the you get grid to decide the width of each item by setting say 1fr 1fr 1fr for wide viewports, have a media query which sets the layout at 1fr 1fr for medium sized ones and 1fr for narrow ones.

Comment: And what should i do with the large amount of space which will be left both sides of 1fr 1fr? After i center it? @AHaworth

Answer (score 0):

You must use the class with col-md-12:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
```

and after this fin your.css file use media-queries.
Hope it will work. Try this out.

Comment: or use FlexLayout if the grid doesn't work